# is it possible to send 2 models to a view ? MVC 4 .net frame

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag

We're trying to send a list and an object to a view but we don't know 
how to send multiple items to the view.

This is our view class

```
@model LolNexusProject.Models.TestObject

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Match History";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Match History</h2>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.matches.Count; i++)
{
<div style="background-color: #8BC34A;width: 600px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <div style="height: 25px;background-color: #689F38; padding:5px">
        <div style="float: left;">
            @Model.matches[i].queueType - @(Model.matches[i].matchDuration / 60) Minutes
      </div>
        <div style="float: right;">
            Creation date
        </div>
     </div>
    //we want to acces the list here (we already tried the viewbag but it didn't work
</div>
}
```

And here is our  controller class

```
public ActionResult Search(string name)
    {
 //get the data from the server
 TestObject test = TestObject();"
 List<long> list = getIds();
        return View(test);
    }
```

Comment: to send multiple models you need to create a view model.  a class that has both objects in it that you send to the view.  http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3

Answer (score 2):

A common solution is to define a `ViewModel` class:

```
namespace LolNexusProject.Models
{
    public class TestObjectListViewModel
    {
        public List<long> Ids { get; set; }

        public int TestObj { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Make it your View Model:

```
@model LolNexusProject.Models.TestObjectListViewModel
```

Pass an instance of it to your `View` from the `Controller`:

```
public ActionResult Search(string name)
{
     var viewModel = new TestObjectListViewModel {
         Ids = getIds(),
         TestObj = TestObject()
    };
    return (viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Another solution would be to use strongly-typed Partial Views (in that case for the list of IDs), which are embedded in the parent view.

Comment: Indeed, a nice idea as well.